# fetch data not working in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im new to react native and my try to get fetch data is not working... Here is what i do :

First I get my data :

```
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        layoutData: {}
    };

}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://www.mywebsite.org/getmyjson.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            layoutData: response
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error : " + error);
    });
}
```

Then I try to map over an array in my JSON data (with rep variable) :

```
    render() {

    var test = {"libelle":"my libelle","reponse": [ {"color": "orange", "text": "14576"}, {"color": "green","text": "my text"}],"image":"rs2016-img01.png","annotation":"my annotation","source":"Source "}


    var rep = this.state.layoutData;

    console.log("//////////////////////////////////////////////");
    console.log(rep.reponse);
    console.log("//////////////////////////////////////////////");
    console.log(test.reponse);
    console.log("//////////////////////////////////////////////");
    console.log(typeof(rep.reponse));
    console.log("//////////////////////////////////////////////");
    console.log(typeof(test.reponse));
    console.log("//////////////////////////////////////////////");

    var t = rep.reponse.map(function(item) {
        return {
            key: item.color,
            label: item.text

        };
    });

    var data2 = test.reponse.map(function(item) {
        return {
            key: item.color,
            label: item.text

        };
    });
```

I get the error "TypeError : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'rep.reponse.map')

Where it begins to be annoying is : 
   1- The test variable represent the JSON I get
   2- All console.logs are the same for rep and test (i.e. rep has the same data and type as test)
   3- I dont get the error with "test.reponse.map"

Any idea of where is my mistake ??

Here is the console log :

I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): //////////////////////////////////////////////
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): [ { color: 'orange', text: '14576' },
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911):   { color: 'green', text: '-4% par rapport ├á 2015' } ]
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): //////////////////////////////////////////////
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): [ { color: '#FF0000', text: '14576' },
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911):   { color: 'green', text: '-4% par rapport ├á 2015' } ]
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): //////////////////////////////////////////////
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): object
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): //////////////////////////////////////////////
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): object
I/ReactNativeJS( 2911): //////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: What is responseJson?

Comment: Sorry its "response", I corrected in my question

Comment: you tried printing the response before passing it to the app or setting in state?

Comment: Please attach your Json also. That will help in understanding more.

Comment: You are not waiting for the response to comeback, i've posted an answer below to explain, If you need further explaination regarding this please ask there.

Comment: The JSON is exactly the same as the test variable.

Answer (score 0):

The initial state value should be like,

```
this.state = {
        layoutData: {
                  reponse : []
        }
    };
```

The rest looks fine, unless your api response is of proper format

Comment: Hope you are using 'response' instead of 'reponse' while logging.

Comment: I had edited the answer, did you try with the edited answer?

Comment: Using 'response' while logging ? Sorry, dont understand (Im new to react native)... Where in the code ?

Comment: console.log(rep.reponse); is what u logs, please change it to console.log(rep.response);

Comment: Did you change the console statement to console.log(rep.response); with the S, not reponse.

Comment: console.log(rep.reponse) displays the json (same with test.reponse). If I change to console.log(rep.response) it displays 'undefined'.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the answer, to set the intial state with reponse. and also pls post the response from your api to verify that the data it sets in the state

Comment: Did you try changing the initial state value to the latest answer?

Answer (score 0):

When the first render happens the fetch request hasn't fired yet therefore there is nothing in layoutData yet.
Also the fetch request is async sop you'll need to wait for it first before rendering.
Keeping a loading state will help you for ex:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        loading:true
        layoutData: {}
    };

}


componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading:true})
    fetch('https://www.mywebsite.org/getmyjson.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            loading:false
            layoutData: response
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error : " + error);
    });
}
```

then use this loading state in your render method like:

```
if (!this.state.loading) {
  console.log(rep.response) //will help you see that the data is received
  var t = rep.reponse.map(function(item) {
    return {
      key: item.color,
      label: item.text
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: What I do not understand is I actually get the JSON (as it displays in console log) but when I try to "map", it says its undefined !

Comment: @L.Prime remove your  console.log statements that are accessing the response outside

Comment: i've updated the answer with the initial loading state too, it should work now

Comment: So, console.log(rep.response); gives 'undefined' and console.log(rep.reponse); displays the JSON

Comment: does that means the api you are calling is sending it to you in reponse? I didn't actually see there might have been a typing mistake as well, I just saw the flaw in the logic :D haha